# How to call static block by xml to phtml without refrence

Tags: phtml, static-block, default.xml

I want to call a static navigation block in `topmenu.phtml`

I defined that in `default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="top_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="top_links" xsi:type="string">top_links</argument>
            </arguments>
</block>
```

And calling in `.phtml` like this.

```
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top_links')->toHtml();?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But its not working please suggest how to do this.

I don't want to call direct on `.phtml` like this.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire contents of default.xml. Is top_links block a child block of catalog.topnav block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines in the `default.xml` file

**From** :

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
```

**To** :

```
   <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="top_links">
            <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">top_links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Now, in `topmenu.phtml` file, just include the below code at desired line.

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

calling in phtml like below instead of yours

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_links') ?>
```

Comment: Is this code working fine ?

Comment: Yeah...Why if you are facing any issue???